# Azure function exception - Error writing logs to table storage: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.StorageException

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure function that communicates with blob storage to read the last sync date time and then based on that, reading the data from the Cosmos database.

Few interactions work fine and randomly throwing the following exception in some cases

> "Error writing logs to table storage:
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.StorageException: An operation on a
> socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient
> buffer space or because a queue was full. --->
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An operation on a socket could
> not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or
> because a queue was full. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
> (10055): An operation on a socket could not be performed because the
> system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full. at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack
> trace --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host,
> Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.TableCommand.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1
> cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext,
> CancellationToken token) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.TableCommand.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.Utility.SafeExecuteAsync(CloudTable table, TableBatchOperation batch) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging\Internal\Utility.cs:line 178 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.Utility.WriteBatchAsync[T](ILogTableProvider logTableProvider, IEnumerable`1 e1) in
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging\Internal\Utility.cs:line
> 268 at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.LogWriter.FlushTimelineAggregateAsync(Boolean
> always) in
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging\Internal\LogWriter.cs:line
> 265 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.LogWriter.FlushCoreAsync() in
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging\Internal\LogWriter.cs:line
> 316 Request Information RequestID: RequestDate: StatusMessage:
> ErrorCode:"

Can any one advise me how I can fix it?

Comment: Hi, can you show the code? Do you use binding or just put the logic in the function body?

Comment: Hi Bowman, Thank you for your comment. The all logic is in function body.

Comment: Also the connection? if in this situation, maybe comes from there are too many connections.

Comment: The connection string is in config file. Yes, I was thinking the same but I did create simple console app to test the data read from Cosmos db, fired about 10k data read requests and  surprisingly it works. So bit confused now where to look into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not share any relevant piece of code from your function, my answer would be bit of generic. It seems to be due to socket exhaustion issue. While there is an inconclusive [similar issue in github](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1127) having some more details, a few good pointers to eliminate any low hanging fruits would be (I highly recommend you to read):

- [Manage connections in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections)
- [Improper Instantiation antipattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/)

The major one I would particularly advise you to ensure shared connection reuse for Cosmos (or Table) client, HttpClient etc in a static private instance outside method.

> ### Static clients
>
> To avoid holding more connections than necessary, reuse client
> instances rather than creating new ones with each function invocation.
> We recommend reusing client connections for any language that you
> might write your function in. For example, .NET clients like the
> [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1&preserve-view=true),
> [DocumentClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient),
> and Azure Storage clients can manage connections if you use a single,
> static client.
>
> Here are some guidelines to follow when you're using a
> service-specific client in an Azure Functions application:
>
> - *Do not* create a new client with every function invocation.
> - *Do* create a single, static client that every function invocation can use.
> - *Consider* creating a single, static client in a shared helper class if different functions use the same service.

Example:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;

private static Lazy<DocumentClient> lazyClient = new Lazy<DocumentClient>(InitializeDocumentClient);
private static DocumentClient documentClient => lazyClient.Value;

private static DocumentClient InitializeDocumentClient()
{
    // Perform any initialization here
    var uri = new Uri("example");
    var authKey = "authKey";
    
    return new DocumentClient(uri, authKey);
}

// Function
public static async Task Run(string input)
{
    Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("database", "collection");
    object document = new { Data = "example" };
    await documentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionUri, document);
    
    // Rest of function
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've just hit the same issue with a Function App I've just upgraded from v2 to v3.

As you note, the exception isn't from your code, but from within the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging`, which is just getting on with it's own thing regardless of what you're doing. It was also only happening locally, and not in my deployed instances.

Based on [the answer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/491071/microsoftazurecosmostablestorageexception.html) I deleted the [AzureWebJobsDashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsdashboard) setting from my `local.settings.json` file, and the error has gone away.

> Internally Functions uses Table Storage for logging if the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` app setting is set. It's recommended to use Application Insights for logging in production scenarios, so you can safely remove this and set the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` app setting instead.

Seeing as I don't need logs stored for local development, and my deployed functions all only have the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` set.